# xsl for-each multiple results filtering

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-grouping

First question on here, so sorry for any formatting errors... I'm having a problem filtering some xml results using xslt 1.0 and have been wracking my brain for a week. I looked around here a bit but couldn't find anything like what I'm trying to do, so I figured I'd ask my own question.

My desired output is a table with rows and columns; can't use actual html here (and i used underscores in place of tabs), so here is a general look:

## Process Log for Pressure Tests:

Step 6 - Pressure Test #1 __
Start Time: 09-FEB-2018 14:21:01 __
Duration: 00:45:00
Date Time _____
Pressure (psi) _______
Temperature (°C) _______
Temp 2 (°C) _______
Drain Press (psi) _______
09-FEB-2018 12:21:01 _______ 4.4 _______ 77.8 _______ 80.1 ______ 0.2 
09-FEB-2018 12:22:01 _______ 4.3 _______ 77.9 _______ 80.0 ______ 0.2 
... 
09-FEB-2018 12:55:01 _______ 4.5 _______ 81.7 _______ 88.2 ______ 1.1 

Step 8 - Pressure Test #2 __
Start Time: 09-FEB-2018 15:21:01 __
Duration: 00:15:00

Date Time __
Pressure (psi) __
Temperature (°C) __
Temp 2 (°C) __
Drain Press (psi) __
09-FEB-2018 15:21:01 _______ 6.4 _______ 77.8 _______ 80.1 ______ 0.3 
09-FEB-2018 15:22:01 _______ 6.3 _______ 77.9 _______ 80.0 ______ 0.1 
... 
09-FEB-2018 15:35:01 _______ 6.5 _______ 81.7 _______ 88.2 ______ 0.9

The xml source is something like the following:

```
<folders NODE_NUMBER="87" RUN_START_DATETIME_LOCAL="2018-02-09 15:21:01.000" 
DURATION="15 Mins 00 Secs" START_DATETIME_UTC="2018-02-09 20:21:01.000" 
CONTEXT_SOURCE="1" UTC_EXPLICIT="FALSE" RUN_TYPE="folders" NUMBER="Step 13 - 
Pressure Test #2" START_DATETIME_LOCAL="2018-02-09 15:21:01.000" 
RUN_STOP_DATETIME="09-Feb-2018 15:36:01" IN_PROGRESS="FALSE" 
END_DATETIME_LOCAL="2018-02-09 15:36:01.000" RUN_STOP_DATETIME_LOCAL="2018-02-09 15:36:01.000" RUN_NAME="Step 13 - Pressure Test #2" RUN_START_DATETIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" END_DATETIME="09-Feb-2018 15:36:01" START_SORTTIME="20180209152101" TOTALSECONDS_UTC="900.0" DURATION_UTC="DAY=0000;HR=00;MIN=14;SEC=59;MS=1000;" TOTALSECONDS="900" START_DATETIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" RUN_ID="{301C81C5-5266-4DEA-901D-5D9B2C285CC0}" END_DATETIME_UTC="2018-02-09 20:36:01.000" STOP_SORTTIME="20180209153601" NAME="Step Time Range" VISIBLE="1" REQUIRED="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1" HIERARCHY_PATH="cycle\folders" START_SOURCE="*" END_SOURCE="*">
<ITEM NODE_NUMBER="88" SORT_ORDER="20" UTC="0" DATASOURCE_ID="10" PSTART="" SOURCE_ID="" TAG="PL" VISIBLE="1" DESCRIPTION="" IDPK="2023" EXEC_CONDITION="" DELIMITER="" PRECISION="1" VERSION="1" OCCURRENCE="" ITEMTYPE="DEFAULT" SOURCE="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1" ID="12062" NAME="Drain Press" DATA_SCOPE="0" PLENGTH="" REQUIRED="1" UOM="psig">
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="89" TYPE="TABLE" NAME="TABLE" AGGREGATE="INTERPOLATIVE" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="28.8" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:22:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:23:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:24:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:25:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:26:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:27:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="21.7" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:28:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:29:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:30:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:31:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:32:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:33:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:34:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:35:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="90" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MINIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="0.2" RAW_DATA="0.200000" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="91" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MAXIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="46.2" RAW_DATA="46.200001" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI105/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM NODE_NUMBER="92" SORT_ORDER="30" UTC="1" DATASOURCE_ID="10" PSTART="" SOURCE_ID="" TAG="PL" VISIBLE="1" DESCRIPTION="" IDPK="2024" EXEC_CONDITION="" DELIMITER="" PRECISION="1" VERSION="1" OCCURRENCE="" ITEMTYPE="DEFAULT" SOURCE="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1" ID="12065" NAME="Bypass Drain Temp" DATA_SCOPE="0" PLENGTH="" REQUIRED="1" UOM="Deg C">
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="93" TYPE="TABLE" NAME="TABLE" AGGREGATE="INTERPOLATIVE" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="23.9" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:22:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:23:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:24:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:25:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:26:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:27:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:28:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:29:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:30:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:31:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:32:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:33:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:34:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:35:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="94" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MINIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="23.9" RAW_DATA="23.900000" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="95" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MAXIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="24.1" RAW_DATA="24.100000" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI106/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM NODE_NUMBER="96" SORT_ORDER="40" UTC="1" DATASOURCE_ID="10" PSTART="" SOURCE_ID="" TAG="PL" VISIBLE="1" DESCRIPTION="" IDPK="2025" EXEC_CONDITION="" DELIMITER="" PRECISION="1" VERSION="1" OCCURRENCE="" ITEMTYPE="DEFAULT" SOURCE="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1" ID="12070" NAME="Drain Temp" DATA_SCOPE="0" PLENGTH="" REQUIRED="1" UOM="Deg C">
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="97" TYPE="TABLE" NAME="TABLE" AGGREGATE="INTERPOLATIVE" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.9" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:22:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:23:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:24:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:25:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:26:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:27:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:28:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:29:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:30:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:31:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:32:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:33:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:34:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:35:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="98" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MINIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.5" RAW_DATA="25.500000" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="99" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MAXIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="25.9" RAW_DATA="25.900000" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI107/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
</ITEM>
<ITEM NODE_NUMBER="100" SORT_ORDER="50" UTC="1" DATASOURCE_ID="10" PSTART="" SOURCE_ID="" TAG="PL" VISIBLE="1" DESCRIPTION="" IDPK="2026" EXEC_CONDITION="" DELIMITER="" PRECISION="1" VERSION="1" OCCURRENCE="" ITEMTYPE="DEFAULT" SOURCE="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1" ID="12075" NAME="Filter Drain Temp" DATA_SCOPE="0" PLENGTH="" REQUIRED="1" UOM="Deg C">
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="101" TYPE="TABLE" NAME="TABLE" AGGREGATE="INTERPOLATIVE" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="21.0" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:22:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:23:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:24:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:25:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:26:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:27:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:28:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:29:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:30:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:31:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:32:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:33:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:34:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:35:01" QUALITY="200C0 (OPCHDA_INTERPOLATED | OPC_QUALITY_GOOD)" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="102" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MINIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="21.0" RAW_DATA="21.000000" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
<RESULT NODE_NUMBER="103" TYPE="CALC" EVENTVALUE="MAXIMUM" VISIBLE="1" OUTPUT_TO_REPORT="1">
<RESULT_RECORD DATA="22.3" RAW_DATA="22.299999" TIME="09-Feb-2018 15:21:01" TAG="10-LSV1-XI104/AI1/OUT.CV"/>
</RESULT>
</ITEM>
</folders>
```

and my XSL is the following:

```
  <div>
    <!--ProcessLog-->
    <table class="Item" id="Item_ProcessLog">
      <tr>
        <td COLSPAN="6">
          <h2>Process Log for Pressure Tests:</h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="Item" width="100%">
      <xsl:for-each select="//folders[@NAME='Step Time Range'][contains(@RUN_NAME,'Pressure Test')]" >
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align:right" colspan="2">
            <b>
              <xsl:value-of select="./@RUN_NAME" />
            </b>
          </td>
          <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
                        Start Time: <xsl:value-of select="./@RUN_START_DATETIME" /></td>
          <td style="text-align:left" colspan="2">
                        Duration: 
                        <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="./@TOTALSECONDS_UTC" /><xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($seconds div 3600), '00')" /><xsl:value-of select="format-number(floor($seconds div 60 mod 60), ':00')" /><xsl:value-of select="format-number($seconds mod 60, ':00')" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align:center;">Date Time
                    </th>
          <xsl:for-each select=".//ITEM[@TAG='PL']">
            <th style="text-align:center;">
              <xsl:value-of select="@NAME" />
              <br>
                <xsl:value-of select="@UOM" />
              </br>
            </th>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="(.//ITEM[@TAG='PL'])/RESULT[@TYPE='TABLE']/RESULT_RECORD">
          <xsl:variable name="num" select="position()" />
          <tr>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@TIME" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="@DATA" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Its "working" so far as to display the date/time for each result and only the first column of data. I cannot for the life of me get the output of all four columns of data. I have a different stylesheet that works with the same xsl that displays all data, not just these multiple subsets of data.

Anyone have any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to look at my question :)

Comment: Please share a well-formed XML. The shared XML has quite a few open `<RESULT_RECORD>` nodes without any closing nodes. Also there is no `<NODE>` having `@NAME = 'Step Time Range'` in the shared XML. It will not be possible to determine what is going wrong based on the XML and XSL shared. Please match the sample XML data with the shared XSL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I was trying to generalize the source because they run between 10,000 and 14,000 lines long and that is a bit large to post here. What do you recommend? Good point on the result record items. I forgot the  /> at the end when I was transposing it. I updated the post.

Comment: Please share sample XML in which the data would qualify for the XSL condition `<xsl:for-each select="//NODE[@NAME='Step Time Range'][contains(@RUN_NAME,'Pressure Test')]" >`. Currently no records pass this filter and hence it is not possible to reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: Hi Aniket V, I updated the xml and xls as requested. Hopefully that is acceptable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data to be displayed column-wise is fetched from different index of `<ITEM>` element viz. `Drain Press` is fetched from `<RESULT_RECORD>` elements present under `ITEM[1]`, `Bypass Drain Temp` is fetched from `<RESULT_RECORD>` elements present under `ITEM[2]` and so on.

The combination of `muenchian grouping` and normal `<xsl:for-each>` can be used to get the desired output. An outer loop on the `<folders>` element is started which is same as the shared XSL.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//folders[@NAME='Step Time Range'][contains(@RUN_NAME,'Pressure Test')]">
```

Within this loop, the header row and column headers can be built. I have modified the shared code snippet to use the `concat()` function instead of successive `<xsl:value-of>`.

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:right" colspan="2">
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="@RUN_NAME" />
        </b>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Start Time: ', @RUN_START_DATETIME)" />
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:left">
        <xsl:variable name="totalSeconds" select="@TOTALSECONDS_UTC" />
        <xsl:variable name="hours" select="format-number(floor($totalSeconds div 3600), '00')" />
        <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="format-number(floor($totalSeconds div 60 mod 60), ':00')" />
        <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="format-number($totalSeconds mod 60, ':00')" />
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('Duration: ', $hours, $minutes, $seconds)" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Date Time</th>
    <xsl:for-each select="ITEM[@TAG='PL']">
        <th style="text-align:center;">
            <xsl:value-of select="@NAME" />
            <br>
                <xsl:value-of select="@UOM" />
            </br>
        </th>
    </xsl:for-each>
</tr>
```

For fetching and displaying the individual column-wise data, `muenchian grouping` is used. A key is defined to group together the `<RESULT_RECORD>` having `@QUALITY` attribute based on the value of `@TIME` attribute. `@QUALITY` attribute filter is used to exclude other `<RESULT_RECORD>` elements not required for extracting data.

```
<xsl:key name="groupKey" match="RESULT_RECORD[@QUALITY]" use="@TIME" />
```

A nested loop is run on the grouped elements and is used to fetch the `@TIME` and `@DATA`

```
<xsl:for-each select="//RESULT_RECORD[@QUALITY][generate-id() = generate-id(key('groupKey', @TIME)[1])]">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <xsl:value-of select="@TIME" />
        </td>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('groupKey', @TIME)">
            <td style="text-align:center;">
                <xsl:value-of select="@DATA" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The entire XSLT is as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:key name="groupKey" match="RESULT_RECORD[@QUALITY]" use="@TIME" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <div>
            <!--ProcessLog -->
            <table class="Item" id="Item_ProcessLog" border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td COLSPAN="5">
                        <h2>Process Log for Pressure Tests:</h2>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table class="Item" width="100%" border="1">
                <xsl:for-each select="//folders[@NAME='Step Time Range'][contains(@RUN_NAME,'Pressure Test')]">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align:right" colspan="2">
                            <b>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@RUN_NAME" />
                            </b>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2">
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Start Time: ', @RUN_START_DATETIME)" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align:left">
                            <xsl:variable name="totalSeconds" select="@TOTALSECONDS_UTC" />
                            <xsl:variable name="hours" select="format-number(floor($totalSeconds div 3600), '00')" />
                            <xsl:variable name="minutes" select="format-number(floor($totalSeconds div 60 mod 60), ':00')" />
                            <xsl:variable name="seconds" select="format-number($totalSeconds mod 60, ':00')" />
                            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Duration: ', $hours, $minutes, $seconds)" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align:center;">Date Time</th>
                        <xsl:for-each select="ITEM[@TAG='PL']">
                            <th style="text-align:center;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@NAME" />
                                <br>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@UOM" />
                                </br>
                            </th>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//RESULT_RECORD[@QUALITY][generate-id() = generate-id(key('groupKey', @TIME)[1])]">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@TIME" />
                            </td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="key('groupKey', @TIME)">
                                <td style="text-align:center;">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@DATA" />
                                </td>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The image of the output can be found in the attachment. I have added a `border` to the `table` for ease of understanding. Feel free to remove it.

[image: Output Data Table]

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a more complete answer. Many thanks!  I appreciate the explanation of each item also, because I was not aware of those type of functions before.